# tinyMCE: how to add shortcut Ctrl+Enter

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

How can I add shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to [tinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce.editor/#addshortcut) (v4) to make it post the form the editor is used with? I've tried this but doesn't appear to work:

```
<script><!--
$('#txtField1').tinymce({
script_url:"js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
content_css:"css/editor.xxm",
//etc. all of my other config goes here
setup: function(e){
  e.shortcuts.add("ctrl+enter","submit",function(){document.form[0].submit();});}
});
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason "enter" isn't one of the "modifier names" that they define. However, you can use key codes. So this works:

```
e.shortcuts.add("ctrl+13"...
```

Had to read the code to figure it out https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/ccff8e084b389fca45399b916261a12cd4418f79/src/core/src/main/js/Shortcuts.js#L50